# Bypass Error Code: 1442. Can't update table as used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

Tags: mysql, delimiter

i wish to do the following,

```
drop database ABC;
create database ABC;
use ABC;

create table head (
head_id int primary key auto_increment,
head_name varchar(55)
);

create table table1 (
t1_id int primary key,
t1_name varchar(55),
foreign key (t1_id) references head(head_id)
);


insert into head(head_name) values ('table1');
insert into table1(t1_id,t1_name) select max(head_id),'HI' from head;


select * from head;
select * from table1;
```

but i wish to use the triggers as i have to this for a long heiriechy, so i wrote following code but it's not working because of mentioned error.

```
drop database ABC;
create database ABC;
use ABC;

create table head (
head_id int primary key auto_increment,
head_name varchar(55)
);

create table table1 (
t1_id int primary key,
t1_name varchar(55),
foreign key (t1_id) references head(head_id)
);

delimiter $$
CREATE
    TRIGGER `t1` BEFORE INSERT
    ON `table1`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        insert into head (head_name) values ('table1');
    END
$$
delimiter ;

insert into table1(t1_id,t1_name) select max(head_id),'HI' from head;

select * from head;
select * from table1;
```

Above trigger is giving me error,

```
Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'head' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

Any help!